# ASP .Net WebAPI does not work with Owin when hosted using XSP/Mono

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mono, owin, monodevelop

I am trying to run a project (**[refer solution here](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp)**) using mono which has `ASP .net Web API` and `Owin` components. The project gets built successfully. However when I hit the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:6666/customers` I get below error.

```
System.Web.HttpException  
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is  temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Details: Requested URL: /customers

Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x000a1] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.4.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/StaticFileHandler.cs:77 
at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest  (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00098] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.4.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/DefaultHttpHandler.cs:101 
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00d9c] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.4.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1335 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.4.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927
```

However, `CustomersController.Get()` endpoint was called correctly which means that the framework was able to go to the correct controller. But something BAD happens past the endpoint.

**Note:** Worth mentioning that normal `ASP .Net Web API` project (without `OWin`) works fine. Issue is **only** when upon `OWin` integration.

I am using:

> Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0
>   Monodevelop 5.10
>   Refer [packages.config](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp/blob/master/WebApplication1/packages.config) for versions of Nuget packages
>   Here is the [WebApiConfig.cs](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp/blob/master/WebApplication1/WebApiConfig.cs)
>   Here is the [CustomerController.cs](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp/blob/master/WebApplication1/Controller/CustomersController.cs)
>   Here is the [Web.config](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp/blob/master/WebApplication1/Web.config)

If you want to give a try please **[refer/pull the code](https://github.com/VamanKulkarni/TestOwinApp)** and import it in monodevelop.

I tried running this solution in windows and it worked fine there.
I am not able to figure out the cause for this behavior. If anyone can provide me with some pointers to fix this it would be very helpful.

Comment: Show routes configuration for API and show the controller in question. Having to down load a zip file to try and reproduce your problem smells of malware. (IMHO)

Comment: @Nkosi: Hosted the source code on github for easy viewing. Also, updated the question with the pointers to the files that you are asking for.

Comment: Took a look at the code and at initial glance, everything looks like it is configured as it should. The fact that It works as intended on windows may mean that the problem is specific to mono. I'll keep an eye out for similar issues.

Comment: Where are you hosting the api when run.

Comment: On XSP server provided by Mono. https://github.com/mono/xsp

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it applies to your issue, [Starting application in monodevelop vs xsp4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21288026/5233410)

Comment: Doesn't look like my issue. Like I said, I am able to hit the action method successfully but something happens after returning from action method and gives me the 404 error. Also, this issues ONLY crops up when OWIN is integrated. WebAPI works just fine without OWIN.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to run your app on XSP then I don’t have a solution for you, sorry. I started reading Mono’s [source code of System.Web.HttpApplication](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/bcaca2dbafcfaad7096ff9fe64bcf81e4d9bddb5/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs#L1176-L1425) to try to understand why the request would be processed by the static file handler but this is an impossible task without stepping over with a debugger.

But if you just need to run your Web API application on Mono, there’s a very simple solution. Since you have converted your app to OWIN, you can use `OwinHost.exe` (from the [OwinHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OwinHost/) NuGet package) instead of `xsp4.exe` to host your app. This worked fine for me with Mono 5.4.1.7 / OwinHost 3.1.0 / Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3 on OS X 10.11.6.

Excerpt from the [OwinHost documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/1653abe19b8740977e368ee0782f1e3eb2c65d03/src/OwinHost/Package):

> Launching OwinHost:
>   Self-hosting an OWIN application with OwinHost is as simple as running OwinHost.exe from your Web application's project directory. Project directory is defined here as the parent directory of ./bin which contains the application's assemblies as well as the selected server assembly. By default, when running OwinHost.exe with no additional parameters, the host will attempt to locate and load the application's startup class and the OWIN HttpListener server. After constructing the OWIN pipeline with the help of the startup class, it will then begin listening on port 5000. All of these default behaviors can be easily changed using parameters to OwinHost.exe, as described below.
>
> OwinHost Parameters:
>   There are a variety of ways to customize the default behavior of OwinHost. For example, to select an alternate OWIN-compatible server, run the following:
>
> OwinHost.exe -s <Custom.Server.Assembly>
>
> The full list of options can be seen by running:
>
> OwinHost.exe /?

Comment: This answer resolved a giant headache of a problem, so thanks a ton. I was trying to convert a default Web Api 2 to an OWIN app on Mono so it would be compatible with a package I wanted to use. The second I changed from `global.asax` to `startup.cs` using OWIN libraries, I would get permutations of the OP's error. My full working startup command on OSX High Sierra ended up being `mono packages/OwinHost.4.0.0/tools/OwinHost.exe -d MyProjectName`